WooCommerce - calculate the shipping charge without tax in some condition
We need to calculate the shipping charge without tax in some condition on WordPress WooCommerce.
Our rule was if user order amount < 50 then shipping charge would be $5 + tax 12%. Its runs fine.
But when we attempt to fire the rule that if user order amount > 50 then shipping charge would be  -$5(-) but WooCommerce automatically added the tax -12%(-) with the shipping charge. We could not remove the tax -12%.
Here is our code:
$item = new WC_Order_Item_Shipping();
$item->set_props(
    array(
        'method_title' => "test",
        'method_id'    => "test",
        'cost'         => -5,
        'taxes'    => array(),
        'tax'    => array(),
        'calc_tax'  => 'per_order',
        'total'        => -5,
        'tax_class'    => NULL,
        'total_tax'    => 0,
        'tax_status'   => 'none',
        'meta_data' => array(),
        'package'   => false,
    )
);
$order->add_item( $item );
$order->calculate_totals();
$order->save();

Please advice us.
